# Portrait orientation in all view controllers except in modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm presenting a modal view with the code:

```
 [self presentViewController:movieViewController animated:YES completion:^{
     // completed
 }];
```

Inside movieViewController, the controller is dismissed with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    // back to previous view controller
}];
```

At the moment, all my view controllers can be viewed in portrait and the two landscape orientations.

How would I restrict all view controllers to portrait EXCEPT the modal view controller? So the modal view controller can be seen in the three orientations, and everything else in one.

Comment: are you going to use iOS 6 or 5?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In appDelegate:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
```

special UINavigationController subclass (if you using navigation controller) with methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.topViewController.presentedViewController) {
        return self.topViewController.presentedViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
    }
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return self.topViewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;
}
```

each view controller should return it's own supported orientations and preferred presentation orientation:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

my app works in portrait, but video player opens as modal vc with:

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
 }

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 }
```

It works perfect for me, hope it helps!

Comment: i had to force landscape with UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft in my video player's supportedInterfaceOrientations to get it working. otherwise i would get crashes. but video is meant to be watched landscape, no no probs.

Comment: No, you need to return all supported orientations as mask and return one of landscape orientation as preferred for presentation.